# how to keep a div inside the Div created by $form->input() in Cakephp and JQuery

Tags: jquery, cakephp

I'm using CakepHP and JQuery for my app.

In my code, there is a line like this which creates a `Textbox` of Labels from the `Attribute` table label column and with id from the table's `Attributeid` column, class name as `calendarSelectDate` (to make use of Calendar of JQuery ) and size too.

Line 1

```
  echo $form->input($r['Attribute']['label'], array('id'=>$r['Attribute']['id'],'class'=>'calendarSelectDate','type'=>'text','style' => 'width:' . $r['Attribute']['size'] . 'px')); ?>
```

Line2

```
      <div id='calendarDiv'></div>
```

Line 1 will create the input text box in a Div of inputtext and now i am having a Div of calendarDiv which is created outside my inputtext Div. Label and text box are within inputtext.

How can I bring this calendarDiv inside my inputtext Div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using on of the 'before', 'between' or 'after' keys that can be sent to the FormHelp::input($fieldname, $options) $options array.

e.g.

```
echo $form->input($r['Attribute']['label'], array('id'=>$r['Attribute']['id'],'class'=>'calendarSelectDate','type'=>'text','style' => 'width:' . $r['Attribute']['size'] . 'px', 'after' => "<div id='calendarDiv'></div>"));
```